# Move large data to the watch

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I want to send a text file to the watch with size around the 2mb.
I tried to save it as string on the data map but I always get `!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer that as an [Asset](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html) or even better use [ChannelApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelApi) which provides an API for sending a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I have an exam after tomorrow so I take a deeper look later.